# how can I extract data from html file using R

Tags: html, r, extract

I want to extract some data from the GEO website, how can I do this?
The URL of the site is http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM410750,
and I want to get the "disease state" of the patient, I used the command

```
readLines("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM410750")
```

to import the html, the information I need is in the 288th line. Could someone help me? Thank you very much. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when questions like this are asked some effort needs to be shown. So please take consideration to state the exact problem with at **least some effort** on what you have attempted next time. To get you started here is an example using the [**XML**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) package and applying [**XPath**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) along with [`strsplit`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) to grab the desired result.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM410750")
x <- xpathSApply(doc, "//td[@style='text-align: justify']/text()[preceding-sibling::br][1]",
    function(X) { strsplit(xmlValue(X), ': ')[[1]][2]
})
# [1] "Uninfected"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am really new in R, so I even do not know how to start.

Answer (score 4):

It might be worth the effort to take a look at the [CRAN Task View: Web Technologies and Services](http://cran.rstudio.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html). There are a host of packages that enable you to read data from web pages far superior to `readLines`. To be truly successful with scraping data from the web you really need to be familiar with things like web sessions and [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) selectors or [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Even with that knowledge, you often still need to use [regular expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) to extract the data you need since many web pages have truly horrible formatting when it comes to trying to use them as a data source.

There's a newer package (not mentioned on that page since it's not in CRAN yet) called [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) that combines a few of those packages into one and that makes doing work like this much easier than before. You can definitely use it and the `stringr` package to get the data you need. The following code is potentially extremely fragile for your use case (it depends quite a bit on how the `<td>` containing the `disease state` is formatted. If you can work through what the XPath is doing and what the regex is extracting, you should be able to tailor it to your needs. Note that it also uses [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)-style piping.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pg <- html("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM410750")

disease <- pg %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="//td[text()[contains(.,'disease state')]]/br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>% 
  html_text()

state <- str_match(disease, "disease state: ([[:alnum:]]+)")[,2]
state

## [1] "Uninfected"
```