# Saving data in text files and loading in R

Tags: r, save, load, read.table, read.csv

I would like to save data from text files on webpage and load it in R. I am having some troubles as I can only 'save link as html' when I right-click the data, which can not be imported. Ideally I should be able to 'save as' a proper text file and load in R with read.table().

The data on webpage looks like this:
[image]

Else when I tried to copy-and-paste into Excel, it could not recognise the columns.

I am pretty sure in the past right-clicking the data would show me 'save as', listing various options of file format. However this time I could not save the data with except .html.

Thanks in advance.

Head of the data after running code:

```
data=read.delim('https://wattlecourses.anu.edu.au/pluginfile.php/2439477/mod_resource/content/1/yieldfert.txt', header = F,stringsAsFactors = F)
head(data)
```

[image]

Output and error after running the code:

```
> data1=read.table("https://wattlecourses.anu.edu.au/pluginfile.php/2439477/mod_resource/content/1/yieldfert.txt", quote = "")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements
```

Comment: So, it's not a ```.txt``` file. You need to ask a question about ```.html``` files.

Comment: Nonetheless, you could try something like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209043/how-can-i-extract-data-from-html-file-using-r. Try this command: ```library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("https://wattlecourses.anu.edu.au/pluginfile.php/2439477/mod_resource/content/1/yieldfert.txt")```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
my_data <- read.delim("http://www.sthda.com/upload/boxplot_format.txt", header = F)
head(my_data)
```

I added `header = F` because the header in your example contains only two elements (`yield` and `fert`).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But the data loaded appears as garbled text. Is there a way to change the available format of download?

Comment: If you could please share the head of your ```.txt``` file, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Could you please try adding ```stringsAsFactors = F```? You could also try this: ```read.table("http://www.sthda.com/upload/boxplot_format.txt", quote = ""```

Comment: Please refer to the edits. Actually the data loaded looks like the underlying code for the webpage.